# fancybox v2 with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, jquery-events

Please someone put me in the right direction, I can't get fancybox v2 to work at all.

it's working %100 on v1.34 but can't get it to work with v2.0.3

**Firebug errors:**

> D.undelegate is not a function
> [Break On This Error]
> D.undelegate(selector, 'click.fb-st...ate(selector, 'click.fb-start', run);
> jquery...ybox.js (line 1270)

**and**

> $.isPlainObject is not a function
> [Break On This Error]
> coming = $.extend(true, {}, F.opts...ainObject(element) ? element : {}), {
> jquery...ybox.js (line 468)

**Here is my code:**

**html:**

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="fmailto" id="mailto{$v.user_id}_{$v.id}">contact us</a>
```

**js code:**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

$("a.fmailto").click(function(event){
    var nr = jQuery(this).attr("id").substr(6);

    var arr = nr.split("_");
    var user_id = arr[0];
    var listing_id = arr[1];

    $.fancybox({
        type        : 'iframe',
        href        : '{/literal}{$live_site}{literal}/mailto.php?id='+user_id+'&amp;ad_id='+listing_id,
        maxWidth    : 630,
        maxHeight   : 600,
        fitToView   : false,
        width       : '70%',
        height      : '70%',
        autoSize    : false,
        closeClick  : false,
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none'
    });
});
});
```

Comment: Are you using the correct jQuery library version for each fancybox?

Comment: oh man, you are right, stupid me how did i forget that. all fixed now. thanks buddy

Comment: no problem. I'll make my comment an answer that you can tick - I guess this is worth keeping around for other people with the same problem

Comment: Also remember that you can't use Fancybox 2 for commercial use without buying a license.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you use the correct version(s) of jQuery. The two versions probably need different ones.